# Difference between two solr indexes

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, nutch

I have two solr indexes , Index A contains 100000 docs and B contains 110000 docs, A is subset of B, i have to perform operation where 
A XOR B = result 
and delete result.

Comment: What's your question? Why doesn't the obvious solution work?

Comment: Hey @Xodarap Question is very clear and I got my answer at http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Difference-between-two-solr-indexes-tt3916328.html

Comment: It is suggested that you [thoroughly research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) your question before asking. Including things that you have tried and haven't worked is a good idea, even if to you it's obvious that you have tried them.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Difference-between-two-solr-indexes-tt3916328.html):

If there are only 100'000 documents dump all document ids and make diff. If you're using linux based system you can just use simple tools to do it. Something like that can be helpful

```
curl "<a href="http://your.hostA:port/solr/index/select?*:*&fl=id&wt=csv">http://your.hostA:port/solr/index/select?*:*&fl=id&wt=csv" > /tmp/idsA
curl "<a href="http://your.hostB:port/solr/index/select?*:*&fl=id&wt=csv">http://your.hostB:port/solr/index/select?*:*&fl=id&wt=csv" > /tmp/idsB
diff /tmp/idsA /tmp/idsB | grep "<\|>" | awk '{print $2;}' | sed
's/\(.*\)/<id>\1<\/id>/g' > /tmp/ids_to_delete.xml
```

Now you have file. Now you can just add to that file "`<delete>`" and
"`</detele>`" and upload that file into solr using curl

```
curl -X POST -d @/tmp/ids_to_delete.xml "<a href="http://your.hostA:port">http://your.hostA:port
/solr/index/upadte"
```